# NVM - All The Packages I Installed with NPM Suddenly Stops Working

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, nvm

I installed Node with NVM as I would not like to use sudo for access permission purposes.

I got the installation of nvm, installed node, installed npm and some npm packages.

The next morning I power on my mac and everything is not working anymore.

I guess `~/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin` is not on my $PATH, but I'm confused as it was totally working fine yesterday.

P.S., The command `nvm` still works on my terminal though.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm(nevermind). I got it working by setting the default to my node version by:

`nvm alias default v0.10.33`

So everytime I open a new terminal, node and other command just works.